# Proof verification of $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac t{\sin t}=1$ using squeeze theorem

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I have been trying this (see the screenshots below). I want to ask whether my answer is enough to proof that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^{+}} (\sin \ t)/t = 1$

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Figures are too much small to read letters.

Comment: See this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Answer (score -1):

Figure are really small to read letters properly but the schemes and information given are sufficient to follow your proof which looks very fine and correct.

Refer also to the related:

- [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

where I've added an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4524220/505767) based on your question with a more clear scheme to better explain the logic of this proof.